# Button below MasonryGridView in flutter

Tags: flutter, button

I have a `MasonryGridView`:

```
@override
  Widget buildPage(
      BuildContext context, AnonymousQuestionnaireDetailsPageVM viewModel) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.questionnaire),
      ),
      body: MasonryGridView.count(
        itemCount: items.length,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
        crossAxisCount: 1,
        mainAxisSpacing: 1,
        crossAxisSpacing: 1,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
         ...
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

I also want to add a button on the bottom of my screen, like this:

[image]

I don't want my button to disappear while scrolling or something like this, just a simple bottom button.

However, when I add it, my code pauses on exception because of incorrect layout. Previously I had not a `MasonryGridView`, but a simple `GridView` with `SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount`, and it worked fine together with button. I needed to replace it with the `MasonryGridView` because my items have different sizes.

So when I just add my MasonryGridView as one of the children to add button as another child after, the program fails:

```
@override
  Widget buildPage(
      BuildContext context, AnonymousQuestionnaireDetailsPageVM viewModel) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.questionnaire),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            MasonryGridView.count(
              itemCount: items.length,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
              crossAxisCount: 1,
              mainAxisSpacing: 1,
              crossAxisSpacing: 1,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
               ...
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Column` and wrap your `MasonryGridView` with `Expanded`, try to follow

```dart
body: Column(
  children: [
    Expanded(child: MasonryGridView(..)
    ),
   ///your button
    ElevatedButton(onPressed: onPressed, child: child)
  ],
),
```

Comment: Glad  to help, you can find more about [layout](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout)